# ExtJS 4.2 pageSize not working

Tags: paging, server-side, extjs4.2

I have a store in which I have mentioned the pageSize config to be 20 and also in my reader I have mentioned the totalCount config. I make the proxy request to a servlet in Java. The servlet fetches data from a MySQL table and builds a json containing 500 rows, and I set the totalCount config in the json to 500. I call store.loadPage(1) at the end. Despite of all this, my grid is loading all the 500 records on every page in the grid. What am I doing wrong?

Below I have given a few snapshots of my code

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'AM.model.User',
    pageSize: 20,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: '/pwbench/FcmServlet',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            totalProperty: 'total',
            root: 'start'
        },
        writer: {
            type: 'json'
        }
    },
});
```

The json returned from the servlet is like this
["total":"500","start":[{....}]]

I checked the grid paging example on http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/extjs-build/examples/grid/paging.html and I can't understand why my paging is not working. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your servlet is fetching 500 rows from the DB and builds 500 rows into the JSON response, then the reason you're getting all the records is ***precisely*** because you are sending back all 500 records.

If you want paging, you'll have to implement some logic for it into either your SQL query (best) or some post-query process to limit the number of rows to match the limit parameter that's passed through in the request (do-able, but not advised).

For MySQL, this is typically accomplished via `limit SOMEMAXNUMBER offset SOMEPAGENUMBER`.

So if your page size is 20, your query might look like:

```
select *
from   sometable
order by column 1 ASC
limit 20 offset 1
```

This would return the first 20 rows, starting at the first row. Then, when the next page was requested, the offset would change appropriately, and so on.

Comment: Thanks. I figured that the totalCount needs to reflect the total number of records in the grid but I need to fetch the pageSize number of records from the table at a time on the server side.

Comment: @existdissolve, might you have any post-query process solution for a JSON response to limit the data?

Comment: The way you would do it (which I highly suggest you DON'T) would be to query all of your records, and then loop over them...starting from the "start" row and ending at whatever "start" + "pageSize" is. This is a really bad approach, though, because it grows the processing time relative to the number of total records in the db...imagine if you had several million records :)

Answer (score 0):

The requests made to the server have three additional parameters when a paging toolbar is defined: page, start and limit.
Try to add `autoLoad : {start: 0, limit: 20}` in your store. And to update your java code according to this parameters.
*Don't forget to add `store: your_Store` in your PagingToolbar

Comment: You do not need to add pageSize to the paging toolbar (it's not even a config for Ext.toolbar.Paging). The Paging toolbar is driven from the store's config.